# Python adding additional code to inline for loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following is totally bogus code.  But let's say you needed to do some extra side effecting function calls (for debugging to logs)?  How would you put that in?

```
[ i for i in range(10) ]
```

Or does one always have to rewrite as a normal for loop?

```
list=[]
for i in range(10):
   otherStuff()
   list.append(i)
```

In C, there is a comma operator for such things...

Comment: `[ some_function(i) for i in range(10) ]`?

Comment: IMHO if function is called for it's side effects, explicit loop should be used. If function is called for it's return value, list comprehension should be used.

Comment: Comma operator in C? What are you talking about?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @Chris Oh, ok. However for the sake of readability I wouldn't use that ever. It doesn't seem worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a call to your side-effect-having code somewhere in your value expression, but you need to ignore that value.

`or` is one possible choice for this. Just make sure that your side-effect function returns a "Falsey" value (False, None, 0, etc.), and put your debug call in the left-hand side of the `or`.

```
def debug_func(i):
    print i, i**3
    return None
whole_numbers = [ debug_func(i) or i for i in range(10) ]
print whole_numbers
```

As an alternative, your function could be an identity function, always returning its sole argument:

```
def debug_func(i):
    print i, i**3
    return i

# Production code:
whole_numbers = [i for i in range(10)]

# Debug code
whole_numbers = [debug_func(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Ps. I agree with others. Don't do this. But you didn't ask **if** you should do it, you asked **how** you could do it.

Comment: It's important that your side-effect function returns a Falsey value here! That's obvious if you've seen this construct before, but less so otherwise :)

Comment: This is purely for debugging a pile of list comprehensions.  I promise to use sparingly. ;)

Comment: @Chris - another option added to answer.

Answer (score 6):

Plainly, don't use side-effects in list comprehensions. It makes your code incredibly unclear to the next person who has to maintain it, even if you understand it perfectly. List comprehensions are a succinct way of creating a list, not a way to call a function `n` times.

For further reading, see the question [*Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

In other words, you should use an explicit `for` loop for that.

Comment: @Chris programmer-time versus ease of use is a common trade off. Best practice is to use an explicit `for` loop. YMMV

Comment: @Chris You want to debug list comprehension? Doesn't make much sense. Just print it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option that doesn't require anything about what your function returns:

```
[(myfunc(), i)[1] for i in range(10)]
```

You can also do more than one function at a time:

```
[(myfunc(), myfunc2(), i)[-1] for i in range(10)]
```